# Lua: Local package.path

Tags: lua, scope, package, lua-5.3

In Lua is there a way to define `package.path` to apply only to a local scope?

I understand I could store the `package.path` in a local variable and restore it before my script ends as in the example below but is there a cleaner way?

```
local startingPackagePath = package.path
package.path = "../Lib/?.lua;" .. package.path
local someLib = require "someLib"
package.path = startingPackagePath
--Do some stuff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a shorter way to make `package.path` module-specific, but you may consider using [package.preload](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.preload) that allows to provide a custom loader, which may look at module-specific path.